# What does unphysical quantity mean?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I was reading this Terry Tao [article](http://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z12azfu4pxm3fbqq404cdvvwas3egfs4dhs?cbp=gz5cg4s34tbp&sview=27&cid=5&soc-app=115&soc-platform=1&spath=/app/basic/114134834346472219368/posts&sparm=cbp%3Dh9me0dqfwrqj%26sview%3D25%26cid%3D5%26soc-app%3D115%26soc-platform%3D1) and almost near the end he says "the terms involving infinity do not make particularly rigorous sense, but would be considered orthogonal to the application at hand (a physicist would call these quantities unphysical) and so can often be neglected in one's manipulations". The article is about how 1+2+3+4... does not equal -1/12 but -1/12 + 1/2 infinity^2 What does he mean by unphysical quantities and orthogonal to the application?

Comment: An "unphysical" quantity is one which has no physical meaning, and being "orthogonal" to something is the mathematician's way of saying they're irrelevant. Like this question is off-topic because it has nothing to do with physics - you could say it is orthogonal to it.

Comment: @AcuriousMind How can an infinite be negligible? What tells you whether they are negligible or not?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I didn't know a better place to ask (I am very sorry)...

Comment: @Pablo no, its fine. Its just that I found ACM's comment funny. Unphysical is a word that is used sometimes in physics, and it means that something cannot be detected, measured, or that it has no effect in any circumstance. For example, you might have heard of Aether theory: it was a theory that proposed that there is a material everywhere, but that it cannot be detected. This is unphysical because it might be true, but if it is not detectable, we don't care about it. Philosophers might care, but not phyisicists.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thaks for the reply, now I understand it better :)

Comment: @Pablo there is another theory that proposed that there is a constant and infinite charge everywhere, but that it has no effect (this description is not totally accurate, it is just a simplified version). They proved that this infinite charge cannot be detected, so it is unphysical. On the other hand, orthogonal means perpendicular, as opposed to parallel. There is a operation used in physics all the time that is called dot product, which gives zero for anything that is orthogonal. This means that *we often ignore orthogonal things, because they are irrelevant*: they give zero when multuplied.

Comment: Divergent series can be "made convergent" to any desired finite number plus an infinity. Not even the mathematical statement makes any sense, whatsoever.

Comment: @CuriousOne what statement makes no sense?

Comment: Why would my question be opionion based?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to use permalink to avoid link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically said of solutions to differential equations which make no sense. For example when calculating skin effect you find that the solution to the field in the conductor is a sum of an exponentially growing term and an exponentially attenuating term. You throw away the first one because it is unphysical*.

* Or because it does not satisfy conservation of energy

Comment: Thaks for the answer, it is funny how I didn't find any info on unphysical quantities on the internet